Twincat 3 / Codesys / PLC code optimization (when doing OOP)
I'm starting with PLC programming, specifically with Beckhoff Twincat 3, coming from an embedded programming background in C/C++ and some C# for cross-platform development.
I've discovered that Structured Text offers object-oriented programming (OOP) features, and I'm keen on leveraging them for code modularization. In non-PLC programming, prioritizing code readability over optimization and relying on the compiler for efficiency is generally advisable nowadays.
Now, my question is: does the same principle apply to PLC programming? In other words, should I fully embrace modularization and trust that it won't significantly impact runtime behavior? Do Structured Text compilers have options for code optimization, like -O0, -O2 flags in gcc? I haven't found anything like this in my IDE yet.

I do not know any ST compiler in any IDE where developer have control over its parameters. Compiler of Twincat 3 is a compiler of CoDeSys and it is proprietary.
You can slightly affect compiler buy some Pragma options in code and some settings of the project. But that is about it. And it is not about optimization but rather some internal logic or how to scope program areas.
Regarding OOP, Twincat has OOP features, but I do not think OOP as a concept belongs to PLC world. I mean you can use inheritance but that does not make program OOP, right? When we discuss OOP we have to define what we mean very carefully. If you make architecture of your business logic as OOP, for instance you make object Heater and methods Start, Stop, properties temperature, ... then you build architecture of your program OOP, and this is not very practical in PLC. I have found that the procedural way is the best.
That is because we have either State Machine, Or Sequential Step Machine paradigm. I am sorry the terms may not be exact in English since I am Russian speaking.
My conclusion after years of development for PLC is that although features of OOP like inheritance, methods, ... might be practical in PLC development but OOP concept as program architecture is not.

My short answer is, I do not know of specific compiler options that impact efficiency.
Now for my long take on your question...
In a certain sense, you seem to imply that, nowadays, programmers can write inefficient algorithms and get away with it because compilers optimize the inefficiency away. I do not think I would agree.
Compilers will improve efficiency at the margins, they will not do high-level stuff like "let us replace this readable but inefficient bubble sort with a quicksort". Lack of compiler optimization may double the execution time of your code. A poor choice of high-level algorithms and structures may cause it to run orders of magnitude slower. I think in the grand scheme of things, optimization was, and still is, not the main driver for efficiency.
You also seem to equate code inefficiency with readability (at least to a certain degree). Maybe there are cases where something that looks like a "hack" will be less readable and more efficient, but in the large majority of cases, I would argue that efficient code is more readable because it is simpler and cleaner. Readability is also affected to a high degree by things that have nothing to do with efficiency, like choice of names for variables and methods, the inclusion of concise and targeted comments, etc.
I think many programmers can get away with a "efficiency or readability, pick one" mentality because computers have so much RAM and CPU power, and there is so few good coders that passable ones can get well-paying jobs. There is a lot of code in use that is both unreadable and inefficient. Unreadable and/or inefficient code is not inherently quicker to write (especially if you include the time spent debugging).
I would argue that most of the time, the code that is less expensive to write overall is the readable, efficient one. Yes, there are times where the quicker algorithm is more complex. Code it in a library, comment it well, debug it once, and benefit from it forever. This tends to be a small (though maybe critical) fraction of the code that needs to be written.
I code relatively large systems, with at least thousands of (highly nested) function blocks and tens of thousands of variables. It has to be highly modular because we assemble cells out of standardized machine modules (the reuse occurs at the "complex machine" level not just at the "machine component" level). I get sub-millisecond cycle times on relatively basic PLC hardware with something like 20% CPU utilization. Maybe the highly modular structure has a bit of overhead (say, 5%?), but the system would not exist without it, as it would kill the re-usability that is the foundational reason for its existence.
I would not say my code is slow (with "slow" being defined as "causing a meaningful loss of value to the user"). I care not one bit about what the compiler does. I pay attention to what my code does, however, caching what can be cached, skipping what can be skipped at any given time, avoiding dynamic memory allocation, avoiding constructs that would create not only long execution times but also meaningful variation in execution time between cycles.
I do not think technology is yet at a point where, as a programmer, if efficiency matters to your application because of its requirements relative to the capacity of the hardware, you can neglect your craft and expect compiler optimizations will make a night-and-day difference.

Perhaps I should have included an example, such as functions: Introducing a function for a small snippet of code can enhance its understandability, as the function name can be chosen to be very instructive. On the other hand, a function call incurs computational cost. However, with a state-of-the-art compiler, this concern is mitigated because optimization will inline the function if it is used only a few times. Do you think PLC compilers do this?

I think function call overhead is not something you should worry about. Making cleaner code will save you time to worry about things that have more impact on the performance, features, reliability and maintainability of your code.  There is a good chance your PLC is going to be 10% busy, with 9% of that being dedicated to "plumbing" processing (I/O and such), 1% being your code's actual run time, and the overhead of function call is going to be, like, 0.0001% of the total CPU time, or less.


In other words, should I fully embrace modularization and trust that
it won't significantly impact runtime behavior?

In a word, no.  With PLCs, sometimes structure makes a difference for efficiency.  I encourage you to experiment to get a feel for the computational cost of different structures & methods.  One advantage of a PLC is that you can easily set up a test by counting the number of scans in a given time, which is also easy to shield from external CPU loading such as from debugging/HMI comms.

Do Structured Text compilers have options for code optimization, like
-O0, -O2 flags in gcc? I haven't found anything like this in my IDE yet.

That I am aware of, no.  I did do some experiments with Siemens / TIA Portal that suggested to me that the compiler skips steps that are 'useless,' i.e. don't make a difference (e.g. 1000 lines of a := b).  But I think you can be pretty sure it's not, say, making functions in-line for efficiency.
